# Problems with Scala actors

Tags: scala, actor

Why this does not work?

```
scala> actor { loop { receive {
     | case s:String => s + " :)"
     | }}}
res0: scala.actors.Actor = scala.actors.Actor$$anon$1@2d382988

scala> res0 !? "hello"
... and it hangs here ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reacting to the given message:

```
actor { loop { receive {
        case s: String => reply(s + " :)")
      }}}
```

Comment: By the way, what would happen if I call `reply` several times?

Comment: With `!?` you wait for the first `reply` (synchronous). After receiving the `reply` the `!?` would be satisfied. Further replies end up lost. [Scala API: Actor](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Actor)